# Default Page Display in Address Bar using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I wanted a htaccess file which would set the Default page for a directory and also display the file name in the address bar.

For example:

In general, if `index.html` is the Index file, then typing the address `http://www.example.com/` would be internally loading `http://www.example.com/index.html` but by default the `/index.html` is not displayed in the address bar. How can we display it.

Like if user enters `http://www.example.com` then the address should change to `http://www.example.com/index.html`

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Redirect from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/index.html`, using `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @shoaibmohammed: have you read up on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule and tried something?

Comment: Im not good in writing htaccess scripts. I usually have been using copy paste snippets with a little modification.